# Can anyone suggest a book on using complex numbers to solve geometry problems?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, euclidean-geometry, book-recommendation

Can anyone suggest me a book which includes everything which is needed for solving simple geometry problems through it? I only know about simple calculations on complex numbers.

Comment: It depends on your background, Cartan's "Elementary Theory of Analytic Functions of One or Several Complex Variables" could be a starting point but in order  to grasp the ideas you should know something more that just the definitions of complex numbers. Maybe it is better to start with a book on Real Analysis that covers also some topics of Complex Geometry (like Holomorphic functions).

Comment: Your phrasing suggests that you're *not* actually looking for a book on complex geometry, but rather on complex methods in elementary plane geometry.

Comment: You should mention specifically what you are looking for when you say that you need a book to address such and such issues. For example you could mention that you're looking for a book which would for instance have information about the dot product of two complex numbers, the cross product, the equations of conics in complex form, and so on. Giving more information enables the person answering your question to be better suited to give an appropriate answer.

Comment: See the three books I cite in my answer to [What are the “real math” connections between Euclidean Geometry and Complex Numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/689034/what-are-the-real-math-connections-between-euclidean-geometry-and-complex-numb). Also, a lot of complex analysis/variables texts (especially older ones) have this kind of material, such as Chapters II, III, and V in [**Introduction to the Theory of Analytic Functions**](https://archive.org/details/introductiontot00morlgoog) by James Harkness and Frank Morley (1898).

Comment: I'm not sure what you are after, but you might be interested in "Visual Complex Analysis" by Needham.  It's a fascinating book, in any case.

Comment: My guess is that "*I only know about simple calculations on complex numbers*" means that Needham's book, and certainly Cartan's book, is way out of bounds. That's why I cited the Harkness/Morley book --- I tried to pick a complex variables book that has a pretty gentle beginning regarding anything beyond high school level mathematics. However, the Liang-shin Hahn book that @José Carlos Santos suggested would be my BEST pick for the OP.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest *Complex numbers & Geometry*, by Liang-shin Hahn.